# Generalizable for loop for all possible 2-way tables?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, contingency

I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face here so bear with me but how do I build a for loop that iterates through a dataframe, creating 2-way contingency tables for all possible iterations?

Sample dataframe:

```
amazon <- c(0,1,0,1,1)
age <- c(1,2,4,3,0)
income <- c(1,1,1,0,0)
delivery <- c(1,2,0,3,4)
manhattan <- c("Manhattan", "Other", "Manhattan", "Other", "Manhattan")

df <- data.frame(cbind(amazon, age, income, delivery, manhattan))
df <- df %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.factor))
```

So all columns are categorical/binary variables classed as factors

I've tried

```
results <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:(ncol(df))){
  for(j in (i+1):ncol(df)){
    table <- table(df[,i], df[,j], useNA = "ifany")
    results <- rbind(results,ftable(round(prop.table(table),3)))
  }
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
make_p_tab <- function(x) {
  col_df <- df %>% dplyr::select(var1, all_of(x)) %>% filter(!is.na(x)) %>%
  table() %>% prop.table(.,1)
}

to_do <- function(df){
  colnames(df)
}

food_xtab <- map(to_do, make_p_tab)
```

And was expecting multiple contingency tables so the output would look as if I'd written out each contingency table one by one.

```
table(df$amazon, df$age)
table(df$amazon, df$income)
table(df$amazon, df$manhattan)...
table(df$delivery, df$manhattan)
```

thank you!

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on desired output - would `stats::ftable(df)` be suitable here?

Comment: No, that creates one big table whereas I'm trying to create multiple tables with one for each possible iteration and then ideally print it out to word or txt or html

Answer (score 4):

Directly use `combn`:

```
combn(df, 2, table, simplify = FALSE)

[[1]]
      age
amazon 0 1 2 3 4
     0 0 1 0 0 1
     1 1 0 1 1 0

[[2]]
      income
amazon 0 1
     0 0 2
     1 2 1

[[3]]
      delivery
amazon 0 1 2 3 4
     0 1 1 0 0 0
     1 0 0 1 1 1

[[4]]
      manhattan
amazon Manhattan Other
     0         2     0
     1         1     2

  :
  :
  :
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there a way to output the tables one by one such as through a for loop? In other words, I want to be able to print these tables out as well to txt or html

Comment: @user1366487 just store them in a variable and subset as required. eg `a <- combn(df, 2, .....)` then call `a[[1]]` to get the first table